# Ubuntu 12.04 icon panel - 1 icon for 2 windows

Tags: icons, panel

Where do I change so that two windows don't merge into one icon?
I hate having to click more than 1 time.

Comment: Your Question is  not clear, plz post clearly to help someone

Answer (score 0):

That's a feature of the Unity Desktop. Like any other UI, there are certain ways and animations that are present in the UI. It's not something that can really be changed.